# How to encrypt a column value on an already filled table with unencrypted data in an existing laravel projects?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, encryption

I have a laravel project that already been running in production but now I want to encrypt confidential data which is **salary** column, here is the example of my table

```
|id|username|email|salary|
|1|xxx|xxx@gmail.com|1000|
|2|yyy|yyy@gmail.com|2000|
```

I want to use [laravel encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption) , so how to update my existing table and continue using laravel encryption

Comment: Run a simple update query to encrypt the existing data?

Comment: Does the field `salary` is an integer?

Comment: @Jerodev can you provide me a simple query that laravel using for encryption ?, I am using postgresql

Comment: @loic.lopez yes an Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running any query into the database I'd prefer to execute this:

```
$users = App\User::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->salary = encrypt($user->salary)
    $user->save();
}
```

You'll need to add a migration to the project in order to change the `salary` type field to text